# How to make force build with interval with CCNet

Tags: ccnet-config

On our CCNet, there is a build (called release) that build the full package of the application and then copy the msi on a FTP server for the client.

There are no trigger on that project and it should be manually launched via CCtray or dashboard.

Is it possible to manually force the project but that the project really start on a fixed time (like 01:00:00) ?

thx,

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `scheduleTrigger` tag.

```
<scheduleTrigger time="01:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild" name="Scheduled">
  <weekDays>
    <weekDay>Monday</weekDay>
  </weekDays>
</scheduleTrigger>
```

You can even specify which day in the week with the `weekDays` tag.

Comment: What I want to do, is having a sheduler that will launch the build on a given time only if I send it a notification. With the sheduler you give, when I do a force build, it starts at once not at the time I wanted

Comment: If you just 'start' the job, it will run at 01.00 (this is what you want!). But if I understand, you want it to stop after that yes ?

Comment: nope, I want to send a command to my CCNet for instance at 14:00 (with all dynamics parameters at that time) and I want that the build really begin at 23:00

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the trigger for your project as TridenT already suggested. Then you would create another project that could only be triggered manually. This second project would be used to collect the dynamic parameters that you need and store them into a file.

In the original project you would add a conditional task at the beginning to check for the existance of that file. You would only start the build if the file existed and use the values from it. At the end you'd delete the file so that it wouldn't trigger the build again the next day.

It is a bit convoluted but it's really the only solution that comes to my mind to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: That's a plesant idea ! I'm gonna try it.